# Record Types in salesforce

Tags: record-type

What is Record Types in salesforce? what are the Types are there ?

i am at beginning stage at salesforce. i could not get exact answer for above questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it appropriate to use Record Types?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38666/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-record-types)

Answer (score 2):

Record types allow you to offer different business processes, picklist values, and page layouts to different users.

Record types are primarily used when you want to identify or "group" records that are used for a similar purpose or where its beneficial to identify them as being "related" or "similar".