# Can I have multiple page views available for the same object?

Tags: developer

I just started Salesforce development this week so I don't really have a strong grasp on methodologies. My main question is can I have multiple page views available for the same object? Also if I’m viewing my contacts, is there a way I could put a button at the top where I could select a certain page view?

Comment: What would you expect to see on each view? Can you provide an example? There's a few features that could fit this scenario, your answer will guide us towards the appropriate suggestion.

Comment: Hi Mark! I want to be able to see everyone in contacts, but when I click on resources (my film makers, copywriters, etc.), I want to be able to change their view to a page layout I created so I can quickly view their talents and what projects they've worked on.

Comment: One thing to take a look at is the idea of record types (in your case on Contact) that allow different fields and different related lists to be presented. See e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUFq1do07fA.

Comment: see also:  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38666/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-record-types

Comment: Hi all, I've created a new page layout.  Within my contacts, I have a view entitled resources.  Is there a way for me to use my new page layout for just the people within my resource view?